# AppReleasebundle not Build

Tags: flutter, firebase

Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

App Release bundle > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: Have You Create your Jks File and key.properties File?

Comment: yes ,i create .but this error show again and again

Comment: Kindly Share image of error